# Java Email: Getting the name to print next to the email address

Tags: jakarta-mail, names

Using Java to send an email, how would I get the name to print next to email address, preferably in this style?:

```
Joe A. Blow <joe.a.blow@host.org>
```

I have my email lists in in a *.properties file with the data like this:

```
email_list_3 = Bob Smith<bob.smith@acme.com>,Jane Doe<jane.doe@acme.com, Betty Crocker<betty.crocker@acme.com
```

I'm using this function to return each email list in the properties file, like "email_list_3", as an array list:

private static ArrayList setEmailList(String email_list_name)throws Exception {
    Properties props             = new Properties();
    ArrayList email_list = new ArrayList();

```
try {
    props.load(MailSender.class.getResourceAsStream("/email_lists.properties"));
    email_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(props.getProperty(email_list_name).split(",")));

}// end try
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Failure populating email list: " + email_list_name + "\n",e);
}

return email_list;
```

}// end function setEmailLists()

Next I will collect the email addresses ( Im assuming the names are still with them? ) into an array of InternetAddresses like this

```
ArrayList<String> recipientsArray    = null;
ArrayList<InternetAddress> addressTo = new ArrayList<InternetAddress>();

recipientsArray = getAnArrayListOfEmailAddresses();

for (String tempAddress: recipientsArray) {
    if (tempAddress != null) {
        addressTo.add(new InternetAddress(tempAddress));
    }
}
```

And this is how I would plug my addresses into a email message:

```
 InternetAddress[] to = new InternetAddress[addressTo.size()];
 to                    = addressTo.toArray(to);

 // processed in a for loop
 tempAddress = (to[i]).getAddress();

 MimeMessage msg  =  null;
 msg     = new MimeMessage(session);
 msg.setSubject(subject);
 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddressStringl));
 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, tempAddress);
```

To me, right now, it looks like to get the names displayed next to the email addresses I have use the other constructor for InternetAddress, that takes two arguments, address and name.

Is that right or is there a setting I can change such that when Java parses the name + address combination items out of my file it will do it automagically?

Thanks much in advance

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this too complicated.

You have a bunch of InternetAddress objects, just use them directly to set the recipients:

```
 InternetAddress[] to = new InternetAddress[addressTo.size()];
 to                    = addressTo.toArray(to);

 MimeMessage msg  = new MimeMessage(session);
 msg.setSubject(subject);
 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddressStringl));
 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
```

It's your use of getAddress() that separates the address field from the personal name field; don't do that.

Also, you can use the InternetAddress.parse() method to parse your property into an array of InternetAddress objects, rather than splitting on commas yourself.